# Regex match nodes with newline only once

Tags: regex, newline

Hi guys I need help really fast. 
Client wants to replace some string in xml tag. XML looks like below there are thousands of such  nodes. I need to match part from  = > < tuv xml:lang="en-US">< seg >ac0037018< /seg > including line break.

```
<tu tuid="2" srclang="en-US">
      <tuv xml:lang="en-US">
        <seg>ac0037018</seg>
      </tuv>
      <tuv xml:lang="da-DK" creationdate="20130211T114451Z" 
      <seg>some text</seg>
      </tuv>
  </tu>
  <tu tuid="3" srclang="en-US">
      <tuv xml:lang="en-US">
        <seg>Ball valves</seg>
      </tuv>
      <tuv xml:lang="da-DK" creationdate="20110801T083108Z"  >           
      <seg>Kugleventiler</seg>
      </tuv>
</tu>
```

However my regex matches whole xml instead of once instance of that. Can you please help.

```
(<tuv xml:lang="en-US">)(\r\n.*)(<seg>.*?)any text(.*?</seg>)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regex:

```
<tuv xml:lang="en-US">\s*<seg>(.+?)<\/seg>(\s*\n)
```

It captures both `tuv` / `seg` fragments.

I think, you used too many capturing groups.
The only reasonable capturing group is the content of `seg` element.

Note that:

- The only capturing group in my regex contains `?` after `+`
  (**reluctant** version), to prevent capturing too much. If you have
  your reasons, add any additional capturing groups.
- `/` before `seg` (in closing tag) is escaped with a `\`, because
  typical regex delimiters are just slashes. If you use other delimiter,
  you are free to delete it.
- `\s` matches also `\n` or `\r`.
- You want to capture the text **including** line break (in the whole
  match), so the last part of my regex is:

  - a sequence of arbitrary "white" chars (may be present before the
    newline),
  - a newline, which you want to include in the match.
- Or maybe you want to capture the newline between `tuv` and `seg`
  opening tags? If this is the case, delete the last part.